# Is System.Data.SqlTypes portable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, portability

Can I use the structures in System.Data.SqlTypes with the Oracle db driver?  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx) says:

> The System.Data.SqlTypes namespace provides classes for native data types in SQL Server.

Is that it?  End of line?  I would really like to use these types but not if they tightly couple my code to a SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There are the [OLEDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx) and [ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbctype.aspx) types...

Comment: Those are enums; `System.Data.SqlTypes` is a namespace.

Comment: It's the best you'll get. Of course SQL Server is better supported in .net